# Show HTML string in ListBox

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone, controls

I just need to show some html content in my listbox (or change text by html tags). It would be just some basic tags `<br>, <b>, <a>` and so. It would be just few tags in whole string.

I am looking for best solution and first I found that WebBrowser could be use with HTML but I don't think it would be good in listbox. Next I found that sometimes people mentions HtmlAgilityPack but I guess it's too big for my problem (I just need to change formatting). I found some controls for showing html but it looks like for WP7 and I know it should work but I don't believe in 3rd party components which aren't updated for 2 or more years.

So what's the best solution now? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already mentioned, you may use a web view to display any kind of html content within your listbo, but if you have several items, you would also have several WebView instances in place and from my experience, they consume quite a bit of memory.

If you have only  a bunch of such tags, replace them with standard controls in your code once you changed the listbox content. This may become a bit complex, but for 
 it would simply mean another TextBlock within a StackPanel. Bold would be a new TextBlock with a specific style. ... and so on.